# why array is taking null value when json parsing in iphone?

Tags: ios6

i am trying to parse json string. but i cant do this using following code, plz help me.
other wise show any alternative code to parse json string.
In code, i got json string. but i cant parse that string in array any dictionary. 
and at end of this method i put three nslog statement and the middle one is showing null value for nsarray while parsing. plz help me or suggest any alternate code.

```
NSString *JsonString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://bia.igreentechservices.com/ws/ws_registration.php?emailid=%@&password=%@&fname=%@&lname=%@&gender=%@&birthdate=%@&mobile=%@&address=%@&emergency_contact_no=%@&other_contact_no_1=%@&other_contact_no_2=%@",emailAdd,pwd,fName,lName,gen,bDate,mobileNum,add,emergencyContactNum,anotherContactNum1,anothercontactNum2];


-(void)callWebService:(NSString *)JsonString {

SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:JsonString]];
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *Json_string = [[NSString  alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
registrationDetail = [parser objectWithString:Json_string error:nil];
for(NSDictionary *status in registrationDetail) {
    NSLog(@"%@ ", [status objectForKey:@"registration"]);// here, this output does not show any out put in conlsole.
NSLog(@"%@",response);

NSLog(@"%@",registrationDetail); // here why this line is showing null  as output in console 
NSLog(@"%@",Json_string);
}
```